# Java bit processing of file.txt

Tags: java, arrays, bit

I want to process a `file.txt` at the binary level by removing every 5th bit if it is equal to 1.  Save the new processed binary file and repeat the process until it can no longer find any more 5th bits equal to 1, then save the final file.

Comment: All files are binary. They all contain bytes. The program reading the file interprets these bytes the way it wants to.

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and explain at a higher level what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Show us what you have done so far and where/why/how it is not working, and you're likely to get more and faster help!

Answer (score 1):

Usually you operate on bytes not bits. If you want to access individual bits, you can use `BitSet` (assuming the file will fit in memory). For example, to set 17th bit to 1:

```
final Path path = Paths.get("file.bin");
final BitSet bitSet = BitSet.valueOf(Files.readAllBytes(path));
bitSet.set(17, true);
Files.write(path, bitSet.toByteArray());
```

Comment: Banthar, I should be more clear.  I want to process a file.txt at the binary level by removing every 5th bit if it is equal to 1. Save the new processed binary file and repeat the process until it can no longer find any more 5th bits equal to 1, then save the final file. Could you advise an approach to this challenge. Thank you.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

All files are already stored as binary. You can get the binary bytes from any file in Java using the [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) api. As an example:

```
    InputStream is = null;
    try{
        is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("myFile.pdf"),StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
        boolean hadMoreBytes = true;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while(hadMoreBytes){
            bytesRead = is.read(buffer);
            doSomethingWithBytes(buffer,bytesRead);
            hadMoreBytes = bytesRead > 0;
        }
    } finally {
        if(is!=null){
            is.close();
        }
    }
```

*plus usual disclaimers about adding error handling & other checks as appropriate for your situation

Note that you will be reading your file in "chunks" of bytes no bigger than your buffer. If you know that your files will be small enough to fit comfortably in memory and your situation demands it, you can build an array that contains all the bytes from the file yourself.

If you wanted to do something with bytes of the file after reading it, you can do something similar using [`Files.newOutputStream(Path path, OpenOption... options)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newOutputStream(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)).

Comment: Sorry, I've been a little slow on adopting the nio stuff. edited my answer to use the newer mechanisms.

Comment: Augray, I should be more clear.  I want to process a file.txt at the binary level by removing every 5th bit if it is equal to 1. Save the new processed binary file and repeat the process until it can no longer find any more 5th bits equal to 1, then save the final file. Could you advise an approach to this challenge. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Augray,  Thanks for the help.  It makes a difference.  My files are not guaranteed to be less than a couple hundred of MBs. However, a file size restriction could be made, but it would be great not to restrict file size.   I do not need to save a file for each pass.  The technique could use an iterative process and could progressively remove bits each time without saving, as long as the 5th bit is equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate file bytes - read and write, you could use [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) or a [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html). An example using RandomAccess file:

```
public void writeAndRead(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {

    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("myFile.bin", "rw");

    // Write some bytes to file.
    file.write(bytes);

    // Seek to the begining of the file.
    file.seek(0);

    // Read back the bytes from the file.
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes.length];
    file.read(buffer);

    file.close();
}
```

My take on this would be something like this:

After reading a byte from you file you could check its 5th bit value by using bit wise operations.

```
byte myByte;
int bit;

...

boolean bitValue = (myByte & (1 << bit)) != 0;
```

After reading one byte, check its 5th bit. If the bit is equal to 1, shift the first 3 bits of the byte to left (remove the bit). Now the first bit of your byte is undefined (can be either 0 or 1). So read the next byte and take its last bit, and insert into the previous bytes first bit.

Do the same shifting for the next byte until no bytes are left. Afterwards repeat the process. Of checking the bits.

You can set a specific bit of a byte by doing this:

```
myByte |= 1 << bit;
```

Looking at other questions in stack overflow, maybe you could make use of [bit-io](https://github.com/jinahya/bit-io).

Comment: Edd,  I should be more clear. I want to process a file.txt at the binary level by removing every 5th bit if it is equal to 1. Save the new processed binary file and repeat the process until it can no longer find any more 5th bits equal to 1, then save the final file. Could you advise an approach to this challenge. Thank you. Michael –

Comment: Update my answer with how I'd try to handle the issue.

Comment: Hi Augray  Do you have an email address that I can contact you?  Regards,  MichaelJava